# Postfix - how can I post incoming email in a different inbox

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, configuration, dovecot

I have successfully created 3 instances of postfix in kubernetes. Each instance checks if the user exists, passes the mail on to dovecot through the LMTP(rotocol) and dovecot saves the email in the corresponding email folder. Example: if the email is addressed to peter.smith@gmail.com, dovecot saves the email in the folder peter.smith. However, as Peter has more than one email, I would like postfix to check if the user exists but then save this email in the inbox for Peter as he has 3 other emails that need to be stored in the same inbox. I want to avoid 3 or 4 different inboxes. I tried to work with recipient_canonical_maps but that did not work.

How do I have to configure dovecot OR postfix to store the email in Peter's inbox instead of peter.smith?

Comment: This is a job for Procmail or Maildrop.